# XEmacs: load all files in /home/barry/.emacs_barry

Tags: emacs

XEmacs creates an .emacs_barry file in my home directory that contain
my active buffers + point positions in those buffers(?). It looks like this:

```
"Norma Jean"

"/home/barry/plan1.txt" 4504398
nil
"/home/barry/plan1.txt" 4504398
"/home/barry/file7.txt" 48480
"/home/barry/file9.txt" 32086
[...]
```

Previously, xemacs would restore my session on restart, but it no
longer does that. I've tried "apropos session" and tried several
commands to no avail.

How do I tell xemacs to load all the files in .emacs_barry? Or, can I
just get emacs to load a list of files in a given file/buffer?

I realize my xinit.el or something is broken, but this is the only 
thing I really miss.

Answer (score 2):

That file is created by the "saveconf" package.  Unless it was dumped with XEmacs (unlikely), you need these lines at the end of your .emacs file:

```
(require 'saveconf)     
(setq auto-save-and-recover-context t)                                                        
(and (null (cdr command-line-args))                                           
     (recover-context))
```